# Combining two indexes in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have the above dataframe and i would like to combine the two indexes so that only 1 remains and it is the addition of the indexes.

Comment: If I understand your question, you actually want the sum of the columns?  If so, you are not "combining indices", but want to "sum" each column.  You can do this by `df.sum(axis=0)`.

Comment: @HillZZa In the above there aren't any 2 "index" at all. There is just one index `0, 1` on right-hand side. Which two indexes do you want to combine or do addition?

Answer (score 0):

Get the 2 lines in the dataset and apply the logic below:

```py
list1 = [1,0,1,0,1]
list2 = [0,2,0,2,0]
list3 = [x or y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]

print(list3)
```

Output:
`[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]`